# SSRS, SQL - Select multiple email addresses as [CC] in Data Driven Subscription

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I'm looking to CC 2 people in a Data Driven Subscription
Here's what I currently have CC'ing one person

I've provided little detail I know, let me know if you need anything else

```
SELECT
eUserName as UserName,  
er_EMailAddress as [TO],  
er_FullName as FullName,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),103) + ' - Outstanding Calls for ' + er_FullName as Subject,  
'firstname.surname@domain.com' as [CC]  

FROM
xxxxxx.xxxxxxxx  

WHERE
er_status = 'Active' and eUserName in ('username1', 'username2')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've sorted it, thanks for your help
it should be:

```
‘john@company.biz; sue@company.biz’ AS [CC]
```

Answer (score 6):

Simply make sure that the e-mail addresses are separated by `;`, that is [space][semicolon][space].

So for example, if you want to send the report to test1@testmail.com and test2@testmail.com, your CC string should look like this:

```
test1@testmail.com ; test2@testmail.com
```

Comment: The dataset cannot be generated. An error occurred while connecting to a data source, or the query is not valid for the data source.

Comment: Sounds like you have an error in your query. Have you tried to execute the query in SQL Server Management Studio, to see if the query itself actually works?